# Check Core Data for existing data. Fatal error: cannot index empty buffer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to store a Username in Core Data.
This means that I need to check whether the username exists in core data before saving the username there.
I recieve an error, and can't seem to find a viable way to do this check. The error messaage is: "Cannot index empty buffer and happens

```
@objc func getCoreData()
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LoginDetails")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [LoginDetails]
    {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Error")
        }
        if true
        {
            setLoginDetails(fetchResults[0])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch code is wrong. Here are the principles of the `executeFetchRequest` method:

- it returns nil if there is an error
- if it does not return nil there was no error
- a fetch without matching objects returns an empty array. An empty fetch is not an error.

You should use something like this:

```
if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [LoginDetails]
{
    if countElements(fetchResults) > 0 {
        // at least 1 matching object found
        setLoginDetails(fetchResults[0])
    }
    else {
        // empty fetch. No matching objects found
    }
}
else {
    fatalError("Can't fetch \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could help with this problem as well? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969356/i-need-a-code-swift-example-of-singleton-model-with-use-of-core-data-update-w